# Known Plain-text Attack

Tags: known-plaintext-attack, ofb, decryption

How can I find the known plain text P2 based on the given information? Assuming that the encryption is made using a common initialization vector and the mode used for encryption is OFB.

```
Plaintext  (P1): This is a known message!
Ciphertext (C1): a469b1c502c1cab966965e50425438e1bb1b5f9037a4c159
Plaintext  (P2): (unknown)
Ciphertext (C2): bf73bcd3509299d566c35b5d450337e1bb175f903fafc159
```

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. Clearly this is homework!. What do you know about the OFB -mode?

Comment: Hint: How are P1 and C1 related? How are P2 and C2 related? Is there a cross-relation?

Comment: @kelalaka an OFB is an improved version of CFB. The basic difference among the two is that in OFB, the output of block cipher encryption is fed as a feedback to calculate the next block. The first block is calculated using an initialization vector (normally a string of random digits and alphabets).

Comment: I managed to solve it.First, I calculated the key by converting P1 into HEX and then XORed both P1 and C1 to get the Key. The key is then XORed with C2 which gave me a HEX of P2. This HEX is then converted finally back to ASCII and I got the answer. Thanks @SEJPM for the hint.

Comment: nice. Welcome to Cryptography. Note: only one can be notified with @